# Showing Inverse Doesn't Exist Locally

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to show that the function $$F(u,v) = [5u^2-v^4, 3uv]$$ is not invertible locally at (0,0) which is true because the Jacobian at that point is in fact 0, but regardless of the Inverse Function Theorem failing, I need to prove the inverse cannot exist at that point. I'm not sure how to explicitly show this because it seems relatively trivial given the statement of the theorem

Comment: $F(u,v)=F(-u,-v)$ I assume that's supposed to be $v^4$ not $u^4$ in the formula.  Also, that you don't mean $F(x,y),$ but $F(u,v)$

Comment: @saulspatz you're right fixed! Also do you mind just explaining F(u,v)=F(−u,−v)? Does that mean there are two corresponding values? thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course.  $F(-u,-v) = [5(-u)^2-(-v)^4, 3(-u)(v-)] = [5u^2-v^4, 3uv] =F(u,v)$

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by @saulspatz in the comments:

Given:
 $$F(u,v) = [5u^2-v^4, 3uv]
$$

One notices:
$$
F(-u,-v) = [5(-u)^2-(-v)^4, 3(-u)(-v)]= [5u^2-v^4, 3uv]
$$

Hence for any non-zero $u_1,v_1$ we can set $u_2=-u_1$ and $v_2=-v_1$ such that:

$$
F(u_1,v_1)=F(u_2,v_2)  \,\,\, \wedge \,\,\, (u_1,v_1)\neq (u_2,v_2) 
$$

Hence $F$ is not injective, and therefore cannot be invertible.